# How to save a unique file from web browser to the local disk?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air

We have a Web login feature. We will offer Free calls to a large campaign.

Scenarios:

- Because of free calls, we will offer a unique file to be downloaded and stored
- After a week or month we will call them and offer them our desktop application to scan and see how trusted, the user is
- If we dont find the same file again, we will never start business and more our own statistics
- Based on that report we want to do some follow ups campaign
- We can do this with cookies but we want user experience and trust analysis

Example: 
if you play a music in youtube.com, without notice your file is actually in /tmp/Flash....flv with lot of data on it.

Question:
How can i do the similar using Flex/Flash from the web browser ? Please kindly advise to any link or existing resource..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant write file on Client PC trough Flash.
You can use Shared Object which are very similar to Normal Files and they will not be deleted in most cases.

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Shared+Objects

Claudio

Comment: I tried this and it seems browser to another browser can detect the same data. But what is the filename those browsers are reading back from ?

Comment: The Shared Object are cross Browser because they specific to the Flash Player. The SHared Object name is the one you use when you create it in the Flex Code. The parameter of this method SharedObject.getLocal('name'); is the name of the file created.

Comment: The files in tmp directory are cache file. They are managed by the browser itself and you don't have the rights to manipulate them. It's not the Flash Player but IE that create them. As I said before Flash cannot create file in the Client PC for securuty reason, only Shared Object.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I just wanted to ask you another question which is related to this, SharedObject if i skip. Can i use simple flex button or action script for have flash networking tcp/udp to connect localhost (not remote hosts) lets say on port 90 ?

Comment: I think this behavior can only make problem. If you try to call localhost on a client machine localhost will be the local system that may not have a local server available, and i think this is the most common case. Anyway i don't think you can do anything useful trying to contact the localhost even if it is available because you don't know what is really installed on the client PC.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. Flex in the browser doesn't have any filesystem access.

The only ways to store persistent data from the browser with Flex are through cookies, browser hacks like the [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) and local shared objects.

Comment: But i still dont get this. if you go to www.youtube.com and play anything it store a the same file that you are watching in your /tmp/Flashxxxxxx which has FLV data on it. How come it store with exact naming and exact unique reference ? I just want to do the same.

Comment: I don't know the details of exactly how it works, but my guess is that they use the [NetStream API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) to buffer the video, and my guess is that NetStream automatically creates and destroys the buffer file.